# Backend Node routes not working after heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have recently deployed my node.js backend using Heroku but now it seems like my routes don't work anymore. It always goes through my error route to return "Could not find this route." This did not happen when I was using localhost whilst developing.

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const HttpError = require('./models/httpError');
const questionRoutes = require('./routes/questionRoutes');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
    );
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
  
    next();
});

app.use('/api/questions', questionRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.url);
    const error = new HttpError('Could not find this route.', 404);
    throw error;
});

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
}
res.status(error.code || 500);
res.json({ message: error.message || 'An unknown error occurred!' });
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

I am not using any environment variables. Here is the heroku link to my backend: https://mealoftheday.herokuapp.com/

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: HI! Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```js
router.get('*', (request, response) => {
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'etsa2/build', 'index.html'));
});
```

Add this file to your routes my issue was solved hope yours too get solved